# Can I submit to an agent before permission to use quotations is finalized?

Tags: publishing

Can I send a finished book manuscript to an agent while I am waiting to receive the permission I have requested to use for the quotes that are in the manuscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since permissions let you use a quote for *publishing*, the permission needs to be granted before the book actually goes to market. That being said, the process you go through with an agent happens before the publishing process, so I think it's fine for you to have some "pending" permissions, as long as you're clear with your agent/editor about which ones are still pending.

Some references:
[Check the "When you should apply" section](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/authors/guidelines/stmguides/3frames.htm)
[Example of a publication requiring permission be granted before publishing, not necessarily before the agent process](http://oceansidepubl.com/permission.htm)